# can't keep data of textarea in an html form

Tags: php, html, forms, echo

I get data from an html5 form using php and i am trying to keep data of the fields and not be cleared.

It is working for inputs but is failing for textarea(description field).

You can see below that i add a php echo as a value inside the inputs but it's not working for textarea.
How can i make this work for textarea as well?

HTML form:

```
<form method='post' action='entry.php' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="username"> Username: </label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" /></br>
</br>
<label for="email">Email:</label> 
<input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/> </br></br>
<label>Title of monument:</label>
<input type="textbox" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></br></br>
<label>Description of monument:</label>

<textarea cols="50" rows="6" name="description" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" /></textarea></br></br>
<label>Select image:</label>
<input type="file" name="file"  ></br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" > 
</form>
```

Comment: Failing how? Please clarify.

Comment: You have a lot of line break elements which are missing the (mandatory) start tag but have a (forbidden) end tag! (You shouldn't be using line breaks to simulate margins anyway though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
textarea cols="50" rows="6" name="description" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" ></textarea>
```

with

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="6" name="description"  ><?php echo $description; ?></textarea>
```

I added the php echo inside the textarea elements and i removed it from the textarea value attribute.
It should do the work.

Answer (score 2):

The value of a textarea element is determined by the text node inside it, not by a value attribute.

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="6" name="description"><?php
  echo htmlspecialchars($description);
?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Textareas don't have a value property.

Instead, you're supposed to put the value directly between the `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` tags.

Like so:

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="6" name="description"><?php 
      echo htmlspecialchars($description);
?></textarea>
```

And you also need to pass `$description` through `htmlspecialchars()`, in case the value in `$description` contains HTML tags like other `<textareas>` or so.

Answer (score 0):

You have closed the textarea tag:

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="6" name="description"  />
```

Need to remove the closing slash, so your php will be inserted into the textarea!

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="6" name="description" >     <?php ... ?>     </textarea>
```

Comment: The `/` is a syntax error, not something that will close it (except in xhtml, but the question is tagged `html`).